# Getting "no table found" error when web scraping with pandas in python 3.7

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, python-requests, python-3.7, valueerror

I want to extract various statistics from a website. Unfortunatley pandas does not recognize the tables presented. Here is my code:

```
url = 'https://u.gg/lol/champions/aurelionsol/matchups/'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
```

`ValueError: No tables found`

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: because it isn't a html table it's Javascript, you need to use selenium to scrape this sort of content : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239392/selenium-scraping-javascript-table

Answer (score 1):

You can use `API` directly.

```
import requests

r = requests.get(
    'https://static.u.gg/assets/lol/riot_static/9.24.1/data/en_US/champion.json?v9.24.2').json()

print(r.keys())
```

Or you lovely target:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_json(
    'https://static.u.gg/assets/lol/riot_static/9.24.1/data/en_US/champion.json?v9.24.2')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
             type  ...                                               data
Aatrox   champion  ...  {'version': '9.24.1', 'id': 'Aatrox', 'key': '...
Ahri     champion  ...  {'version': '9.24.1', 'id': 'Ahri', 'key': '10...
Akali    champion  ...  {'version': '9.24.1', 'id': 'Akali', 'key': '8...
Alistar  champion  ...  {'version': '9.24.1', 'id': 'Alistar', 'key': ...
Amumu    champion  ...  {'version': '9.24.1', 'id': 'Amumu', 'key': '3...
...           ...  ...                                                ...
Zed      champion  ...  {'version': '9.24.1', 'id': 'Zed', 'key': '238...
Ziggs    champion  ...  {'version': '9.24.1', 'id': 'Ziggs', 'key': '1...
Zilean   champion  ...  {'version': '9.24.1', 'id': 'Zilean', 'key': '...
Zoe      champion  ...  {'version': '9.24.1', 'id': 'Zoe', 'key': '142...
Zyra     champion  ...  {'version': '9.24.1', 'id': 'Zyra', 'key': '14...

[147 rows x 4 columns]
```